# log and rand() gives not a number

Tags: c++, random, vector, while-loop

In the following part of code:

I want to generate a random number "U" from the range 0 to 1,
then I calculate an equation having log

The error is: some value of U makes the log in the equation give "not a number"value

I tried casting the "U" to float or double or even round it to 2 decimal places but same error

```
vector <double>Xs;//random Xs
double x;
double U;

   while (check_arr < 360)
    {

        U = ((rand() / RAND_MAX) * 100) / 100;
        x = (log10(1 - U)) / (-1 / a);
        Xs.push_back(x);

    }
```

Comment: What happens if `U` becomes 1?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems with your code.

rand() returns an integer, and RAND_MAX is an integer, so when you divide them you get an integer which will almost always be zero (since rand() can produce the value RAND_MAX - one time in 2^31 on my computer - and that division will produce 1).

Next, multiplying then dividing by 100 is doing nothing. The result will be the same: an integer that's almost always 0, sometimes 1.

Finally, you must avoid taking the log10 of zero. This value is disallowed and will raise the divide-by-zero exception (also, negative values would raise the invalid floating point exception).

Perhaps you could use the following expression instead:

```
U = (rand() % 100)/100.0;
```

This will give you a value of U with a distribution from 0.00 up to 0.99 inclusive. When you then take log10(1-U) you won't get an exception.

Comment: Note: While you have somewhat the right idea, `(rand() % 99 ) / 100.0` is wrong for two reasons. First, it needs to be modulo 100, not 99, and second using modulo with a non-power-of-two number at all means bad karma (it "looks OK", but in reality the distribution is biased, and that may give weird problems that are hard to pinpoint).  `(rand() & 255 ) / 255.0` is much better.

Comment: Quite right about 99 vs 100 - I edited it above - sorry for the slip. But in regard to the distribution; if the OP cares then he shouldn't use rand() at all as the standard implementations (multiplicative congruential PRNG) have very poor entropy in the lower bits. Using any modulo operation makes this worse, not better, and arguably a power-of-two operation is worse than a decimal one. I divided by 100.0 because he said he had tried rounding to 2 decimal places, and that's what this does.

Answer (score 1):

[log10()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/) will return "not a number" when the parameter being passed to it is 0. When I ran the method on my machine the result that I got was "-1.#INF000000000000". `log(0)` is an invalid number. You can verify this by opening the calculator on your PC (if you are using windows), switch to scientific mode then try to do log 0.

**Mathematical explanation:**

The log base 10 function is used to help find the exponent `y` in `10^y=x`. So when you are trying to plug in 0 in the function you are trying to find a solution to the following:

```
10^y=0
```

But there are no solution to this so instead the function will return an invalid number. It would be better if you set the range of the x value to 0 < x <= 1 so you will not have that same issue.

Since the [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand) function returns a value between 0 and `RAND-MAX` you can be able to use the following to ensure that you will not input 0 into the log function:

```
U = (rand() % 100 + 1)/100;
```

This will return a range of 0.01 and 1. You can mess around with the numbers to increase/decrease the range.